# Replace text in a file and add numbering to the new string

Tags: perl, sed, awk

I want to replace every occurrence of a string in a file but in a way that the new text will be numbered. Example:

from:

```
foo bar a
foo bar b
foo bar c
```

to:

```
bar baz1 a
bar baz2 b
bar baz3 c
```

How to do this in command line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way with `awk`:

```
$ awk '{gsub(/foo bar/,"bar baz"++i)}1' file
bar baz1 a
bar baz2 b
bar baz3 c
```

Comment: +1. You could just use NR instead of ++i if you like.

Comment: @EdMorton isn't enough information, assumed occurrence doesn't necessarily occur once per line.

Comment: sub() is fine enough.

Comment: @BMW refer to my previous comment.

Answer (score 2):

```
perl -lape '@F[0,1] = ($F[1], "baz". ++$i); $_= "@F"' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Using shell.

```
#! /usr/bin/bash

i=0
while read a b c
do
  ((i++))
  echo "bar baz$i $c"
done < file
```